# regex to search patern and give output as string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need assistance with following regex.

```
string = 'IP Interface Status for VRF "VRF_CLOUD"(3)'
str1 = re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', string)
```

This gives output as list: `['VRF_SERVICES_S3']`

I need output as string, not list. how to

Answer (score 0):

Get the first element from the list

```
str1 = re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', string)[0]
```

Alternatively, You can use re.search as well

```
import re
string = 'IP Interface Status for VRF "VRF_CLOUD"(3)'
str1 = re.search(r'"(.*?)"', string)
result = str1.group(0) if str1 else ""
print(result)
```